# What do I do with ClojureScript One?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

This is a wonderful project, but where to start?

I thought about making my own github fork for my own project. Or making a branch for each project "inside" of it.

Perhaps I do not really understand this social coding stuff yet -- but I am really feeling the allergy I have with "encapsulated" or "encapsulating" software frameworks and development environments.

Should one make a project inside of the source files, sitting next to the `one.sample` app? There are so many directories I do not know where to begin. Shouldn't most of the One project be sitting in clojars for us to use and spit out our own app templates, a bit like `lein noir new <appname>`?

Any and all insights appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [episode 3](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2012/01/12/podcast-episode-003) of the Think Relevance podcast Brenton Ashworth says that at the moment there are three ways to take advantage of ClojureScript One (18min 38sec):

1. Copy the ClojureScript One project into your own project
2. Fork the ClojureScript One repo, delete the sample application, and build your own application inside the ClojureScript One project
3. Look at how CloureSript One handles dependencies, and then use the same approach to setup ClojureScript One as a dependency of your own project.

Sounds like the project team are aware of this being awkward at the moment, and they hope to be able to come up with a better story for this in the future.

Answer (score 5):

To be honest with you.... I've had a ridiculous amount of trouble with clojurescript one. There's just too much code to work with and its good for a reference but not when beginners to clojurescript are just starting out.

The best way to get started with clojurescript is with chris granger's 
https://github.com/ibdknox/cljs-template

start your project with:

```
lein new cljs-template <your project name>

cd <your project name>

lein run
```

That's it... just go into the src/client directory and start coding! basically, the template gives you a complete project that:

- serves pages through ring
- has cljs compilation on save so there is no need to muck around with lein cljsbuild

There is a 'clone' of clojurescript-one https://github.com/zcaudate/cljs-template-one made using cljs-template as a guide. It can be used as a project template:

```
lein new cljs-template-one <your project name>
cd <your project name>
chmod +x bootstrap.sh && ./bootstrap.sh

lein run
```

The project uses the twitter/bootstrap html template and can be viewed here:
    http://cljs-bootstrapped.herokuapp.com/

Comment: How do you get the clojurescript repl using your approach?

Comment: I just use cljsbuild - https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild - and run `lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-listen` in the project folder

Comment: You seem to be missing some crucial information here - I have lein installed and ran `lein new cljs-template <your project name>` but lein run complains about missing :main.

Comment: Hmmm what version of lein are you using?

Answer (score 0):

ClojureScript One have a great wiki pages: https://github.com/brentonashworth/one/wiki. They seem very helpful.